# Email chegando em branco com PHP

Tags: php, html

Fiz um pequeno formulário para testar a função mail, o e-mail está sendo enviado porém chega com os campos nome e mensagem em branco. Vi outros fóruns e eles indicam outras bibliotecas mas queria saber no que estou errando.

```
<form action="enviar.php" method="post">

    <label for="nome">Nome:</label>
    <input type="text" name="nome" required><br><br>

    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" required><br><br>

    <label for="mensagem">Mensagem:</label>
    <textarea name="mensagem"></textarea><br><br>

    <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar">

</form><!-- FORM -->
```

PHP

```
<?php

$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$mensagem = $_POST['mensagem'];
$titulo = 'Email Curso PHP';
$dest = 'leonardoh481@gmail.com';
$dados = 'Nome :'.$nome." Email: ".$email." Destinatário: ".$dest." Mensagem: ".$mensagem;

mail($dest, $titulo, $dados);


?>
```

Comment: Verificou se os valores estão chegando corretamente em `$_POST`?

Comment: Sim, mas consegui fazer funcionar colocando tudo get. Está correto desta forma?

Answer (score -4):

```
<?php

$nome = $_REQUEST['nome'];
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$mensagem = $_REQUEST['mensagem'];
$titulo = 'Email Curso PHP';
$dest = 'leonardoh481@gmail.com';
$dados = 'Nome :'.$nome." Email: ".$email." Destinatário: ".$dest." Mensagem: ".$mensagem;

mail($dest, $titulo, $dados);
```

se Estiver num ambiente Linux verificar se tem permissão de leitura/escrita

Comment: Sua resposta parece exatamente a mesma do autor da pergunta. Tente não postar apenas código, explique como resolver o problema.

Comment: resolve o probelma mudando o $_POST pro $_REQUEST,não expliquei pois acho que dá para entender a diferença